# How to add ARRAYFORMULA to header cell in column above data cells?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am displaying formula ouput data in column J. The input for the calculation is data referenced in other columns. The working formula is as follows:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(regexmatch(B2:B,"call"),100*(G2:G*D2:D),"")
```

Here is a screenshot of my columns:

[image]

The problem is I am running a script after the data is loaded that deletes rows with 0 in column J. Because the formula is in J2 the delete script deletes the 2nd row and then the formula along with it, so the cells in column J end up all being blank.

I think I need to add the formula to J1 -- the cell with "Calls" -- so that the formula isn't deleted with the row, but I can't figure out how to do this. How do I add the formula to J1 so that the formula ignores cell J1 and only executes on the cells below? Or where else do I put the formula so it is not deleted?

Comment: Rather than `ARRAYFORMULA()` use `BYROW()` or `MAP()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `VSTACK()` function.

```
=VSTACK("Calls",ARRAYFORMULA(if(regexmatch(B2:B,"call"),100*(G2:G*D2:D),""))
```

Put above formula to `J1` cell.

Comment: Interesting. I've never heard of VSTACK before. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it...

```
={"Calls";ARRAYFORMULA(if(regexmatch(B2:B,"call"),100*(G2:G*D2:D),"")}
```